# Plotting a piecewise function

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I'm having trouble plotting the piecewise function below. The only way I can replicate this function is using

`Plot[Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}], {x, -10, 10}]`

When I define the piecewise function as:

```
unitstep[x] = Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}]
```

and then plot `unitstep[x]`, the graph turns out linear.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Your second function is not proper *Mathematica* code. Can you post the commands exactly as you have them in your notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have apparently missed reading the [documentation on defining functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

If you define `unitstep` (not a good name) as follows

```
unitstep[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x >= 0}, {0, x < 0}}]
```

then it plots as you would expect

[image: plot]