# Plotting a piecewise function in Mathematica 10.0

Tags: plotting, piecewise

How to I plot the following function in one diagram: from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the function has to equal $\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|$ and from $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the function $\exp\left(-\frac{x}{220}\right)$ starts untill that function hits the following bump of $\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|$ and when that happends the function $\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|$ starts again and so on.

Comment: see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138040/9490, and http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/215621

Comment: @JasonB. I saw those links before, but I don't get it because I have the property that the two functions hit/cross eachother

Comment: Your question isn't really clear as written.  Are you looking for something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zveJN.png)?

Comment: @JasonB. This is maybe better:

$$
\begin{cases}
y=\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{when}\space0\le x<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\\
\color{red}{y=\exp\left(-\frac{x}{220}\right)\space\space\space\text{when}\space\frac{\pi}{2}\le x<\left(\left|\sin\left(x\right)\right|=\exp\left(-\frac{x}{220}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\dots\right)}
\end{cases}
$$

For the red part: when you solve $x$ it has to be between the following boundaries:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

And then then it starts again. So it is periodic in $x$.

Comment: You can see here `Plot[{Exp[-x/220], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 30}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {(Exp[-#1/220] - Sin[#1]) & }, Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]
 ]` that your two functions intersect twice per period.  Do you mean for the discontinuities in the piecewise function to occur at these points?  Could you add a graphic to show what you mean?  Also, add the expanded equation to the post, rather than as a comment

Comment: @JasonB. Well the function in the beginning consits of a absolute value sine function, not a regular one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.

```
f[x_] :=
  With[{u = Mod[x, 3 π/2]},
    Piecewise[{{Abs[Sin[u]], 0 <= u < π/2}, {E^(-u/229), π/2 < u <= 3 π}}]]

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 3 π}]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

Try coding your function instead:

```
K = 20;
f[x_] := If[-Sin[Mod[x, \[Pi]]] Sign[Cos[Mod[x, \[Pi]]]] > 0, 
Max[Abs[Sin[Mod[x, \[Pi]] - \[Pi]/2]], Exp[-(Mod[x, \[Pi]])/K]], 
Exp[-(Mod[x, \[Pi]])/K]];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

Comment: You could do this a bit more succinctly as `Plot[ Min[{ Abs[ Sin[x]], Exp[-x/220]}], {x,0,20}]`

Comment: Well, this is not what I mean. I mean something like this but not quite: Plot[{Piecewise[{{Abs[Sin[x + (Pi/2)]], -Pi/2 < x <= 0}}], 
  Piecewise[{{Abs[Sin[x + (Pi/2)]], Pi/2 < x <= Pi}}], 
  Exp[(-x)/(1000*220*10^(-3))]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]

Comment: @Jan don't use piecewise because you don't know regions. Instead, write a function as a piece of code and plot it. Also I don't really get how your funciton looks like, please make a sketch of it.

Comment: @VsevolodA. It is the function that you get when you want to plot the output voltage of a full bridge rectifier (see the picture in this link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/351453/voltage-function-after-a-capacitor-filter-in-a-full-bridge-rectifier).

Comment: @Jan I can see that flat parts of the plot do not lie on one smooth curve. Instead, they look like a function that is drawn from different origins. Is that correct?

Comment: yes as I described in my question

Comment: @Jan you said it's exponent of -x/200, but it's really not since x is always shifted and it's not the same x as in sin[x]. Since your function as described now is periodic, you can use it like this:

Comment: @Jan check out this answer edit with K=200.